# Switching CSS files with javaScript doesn't work with input button POST method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how switch between two css styles in my template so I can change make a multi-language website , to do that I created a form with two input buttons :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" id="style1" name="ar" value="Style1" /><br>
     <input type="submit" id="style2" name="en" value="Style2" />
</form>
```

The code I'm using for the jQuery function :

```
$('#style1').click(function (){
   $('link[href="layout/css/ltr_theme.css"]').attr('href','layout/css/rtl_theme.css');
});
$('#style2').click(function (){
   $('link[href="layout/css/rtl_theme.css"]').attr('href','layout/css/ltr_theme.css');
});
```

The style changes just for a millisecond and then returns to it's previous style.
FYI, I tried another way by replacing `<input/>`with `<a><a/>`, and it worked, but the reason I need an input method is to call another script in PHP with POST method to include a language file at the same time. 
Hope I can find someone to help me figure this out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the submit button the page refreshes itself (since it's sending a POST request and you're not using AJAX to handle it). So you'll need to use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

When you click the link it doesn't refresh the page since the link is local (#style).

Comment: Thank you @Runnick , I'll try with AjAX.

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
$('#style1').click(function (){
```

To this...

```
$('#style1').click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Repeat for the second button.

This will prevent the page from reloading as a result of the form submission.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but the problem pops up here is that the php script won't be implemented if the page not reloading. So the language won't change @WebCode.ie